Given a formula how can we figure out if it is CNF or DNF
Can anyone please help me understand if the following formulas are DNF, CNF, both CNF and DNF, and neither CNF nor DNF? From my understanding, CNF is a conjunction of disjunction literals and DNF is a disjunction of conjunction literals. Can we also consider a single literal as CNF or DNF?
I have listed down some formulas below. without simplifying the formulas can anyone explain if we can determine if they are CNF or DNF
1.[(p ∨ ¬q) ^ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r)] v (¬p ^ r) 

2.¬p ^ q ^ ¬r

3.p v ¬¬q

4.¬q

5.¬(¬p v q) v r


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Apply definitions: CNF "is a conjunction of one or more clauses, where a clause is a disjunction of literals" where DNF "is a disjunction of one or more conjunctions of one or more literals."

Remember that conjunctions can conjunct any number of terms, and same for disjunctions. Thus, for example, $p$ can be seen as a conjunction that conjuncts 'together' a single term $p$. But $p$ can also be seen as a disjunction: a disjunction of a single term $p$.
As such, a statement like $p \lor q$ is in DNF as well as CNF.
It is in DNF, because it is a disjunction of two terms, $p$ and $q$, and each of those terms is a conjncrtion of literals: $p$ is a conjunction of a single term $p$ that is a literal ... and same for $q$.
But $p \lor q$ is also in CNF:  it is conjunction of a single term, that being $p \lor q$, and $p \lor q$ is clearly (because it is a 'normal') disjunction of literals.
Also:
Since CNF/DNF is a con/disjunction of a dis/conjunction of literals, that means that a negation can only occur as part of a literal, i.e. in front of an atomic proposition. Hence, you cannot have a negation of a negation, or a negation of a conjunction or a negation of a disjunction.

If i understand correctly
1.[(p ∨ ¬q) ^ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r)] v (¬p ^ r) =  DNF
2.¬p ^ q ^ ¬r =  CNF
3.p v ¬¬q =  DNF 
4.¬q  = DNF and CNF
5.¬(¬p v q) v r =  DNF

@Supercode  You're right about 4, but wrong about all others.  Something like $\neg \neg p$ is not in CNF or DNF since it is not a literal,  or any con/disjunction thereof.  Also, something like $p \lor (q \land r)$ is not in CNF, since in CNF you cannot have conjunctions as part of a disjunction.
